# Update to Mathjax 2.7.2 please

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

Physics.stackexchange currently uses 2.7.1 with the config TeX-AMS_HTML-full which is affected by a visual glitch on both desktop and mobile version of Safari under latest OS, `\vec{x}` results in the arrow displayed too far to the right ([issue #1737](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1737)). This has been fixed in 2.7.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about that. I didn't realize the beta was over.

We're on v2.7.2 network-wide now.

Comment: Ah, what's an extra day or two? It's only Safari that's majorly affected, anyways, and who uses that?

Comment: Along which lines, maybe it's time to provide updated answers to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15598/ and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66921/?